# Heegaard Floer Homology of double branched cover

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, branched-covers, heegaard-floer-homology

The question is the following:

Let $K\subset S^{3}$ be a knot, consider the double branched cover $Y$ of $S^{3}$ over $K$. We know $Y$ has a unique spin structure $\mathfrak{s}$, now the question is:

When do we have $\widehat{HF}(Y,\mathfrak{s})\cong \mathbb{Z}$? If yes, what do we know about the d-invariant?

I know that this is true for quasi-alternating knot, however, I don't know any other examples...

Comment: It definitely holds whenever $K$ is (Khovanov-reduced, I believe) homologically thin, and when $K$ is a 2-bridge knot. The first case follows from the spectral sequence defined by Ozsvath-Szabo, the second from the classical fact that double covers branched over 2-bridge knots are lens spaces.

Answer (score 5):

The paper of Manolescu and Owens "A concordance invariant from the floer homology of double branched covers" seems to answer your question.  They compute many examples of the Froyshov/d-invariant in their paper, using software of Saso Strle.  It's available on the arXiv.  In that case it's at least reasonably-computable.

Answer (score 3):

Let assume $Y$ is a closed oriented rational homology sphere.

The set of spin$^c$ structure of $Y$ is in one to one correspondence with $H_1(Y,\mathbb{Z})$. So if $H_1(Y,\mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$ then there are more than one spin$^c$ structure.

The question then becomes:  When does $\widehat{HF}(Y,\mathfrak{s}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for each spin$^c$ structure $\mathfrak{s}$?

Three-manifolds with such property are called $L$-spaces. Double branched cover of quasi-alternating knots (in $S^3$) are L-spaces. I think your question is a work in progress. For some other examples see   Steven Sivek  comment below.

Note also that the collection of quasi-alternating knots contains the collection of alternating knots, and  2-bridge knots are examples of alternating knots.

In the special case  $H_1(Y,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, in which situation there is a unique spin$^c$ structure, it is conjectured that $S^3$ and the Poincar\'e homology sphere ($\Sigma=S^3/I$ where $I$ is the full icosahedral group) are the only such 3-manifold. We know that $d(S^3)=0$ and that $d(\Sigma)=\pm 2$ depending on the orientation you chose. For the general case I think knowing exactly the $d$-invariant is still an open problem except when $Y$ is a lens space in which case there is a formula for each $d$ invariant.

Comment: There are actually lots of non-QA knots whose branched double covers are L-spaces.  See section 6.1 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5261.pdf for some discussion and explicit examples, including the $P(p_1,\dots,p_n,-q) $ pretzel knots where $p_i,q>0$ and $q = \min(p_1,\dots,p_n)$.

Answer (score 3):

John Baldwin said something about both questions in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3624) paper. He considers closures of 3-braids and classifies which of these have an $L$-space branched double cover (Theorem 4.1). He then computes the correction term for the spin structure (Theorem 5.1); he also seems to say that there are no new results in this last computation (see the discussion before the statement of the theorem).